# Adding a custom class to Radio Buttons in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, razor-2

I'm trying to add Bootstrap classes to a set of radio buttons.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Male, !Model.Male) Female
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Male, Model.Male) Male
```

Just don't seem to get the right way of doing it. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Male, !Model.Male, new { @class = "female"})
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Male, "Female", new { @class = "female"})

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Male, Model.Male, new { @class = "male"})
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Male, "Male", new { @class = "male"})
```

Comment: I tried this, but this doesn't work on the labels. I want the words 'Male' and 'Female' to render in a particular manner.